# Where does Narad muni live?

Tags: lokas, narada

Every Devta and Devia has a specific place as home. We can see that only Narad muni keeps travelling across all the *lokas* everytime.

Where is his home location? Or is there any reason that he has to keep travelling across all the *lokas* continuously?

Comment: Narad muni is one who is allowed to go anywhere at anytime that's why is  a trylokya-ramani or the one who can roam or is roaming in 3 worlds viz heaven,hell,mrutuloka(earth or physical universe)

Comment: Yes, he is, but I think he has some kind of "shrap" that he has to keep moving from one place to another. I want to know this story.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the start of Satya yuga, *Narad muni* misguided *Daksha Prajapati*'s all sons, to take *Sanyaas* and perform meditation for *Lord Shiva*.

Because of this, *Daksha*'s sons declined to marry and to accept society. They all went to jungle to perform meditation.

This made *Daksha Prajapati* worried about how he will handle the kingdom, because he will not have any successors. He asks his sons who misguided them.

When *Daksha* knows *Narad* is the root cause, he curses *Narad muni*, that he will not have any home/family and will have to travel places, here and there with chanting of *Narayana*.

*Narad muni* accepts his curse as the curse states the chanting of Narayana.

As per Hindu scriptures, *Narada* does not have any home, but he has spent most of time in traveling only.

From [Vedabase](http://vedabase.com/sb/6/5/en1),

> **SB 6.5.43:** You have made me lose my sons once, and now you have again done the same inauspicious thing. Therefore you are a rascal who does not know how to behave toward others. You may travel all over the universe, but I curse you to have no residence anywhere.

Comment: `As per Hindu scriptures`.. which scripture? Please provide source..

Comment: I updated with a source. please always try to have source for your claims otherwise this site will look like full of opinion-based answers. (_please rollback and edit with your own source if you think the source is wrong_)

Comment: Chanting of *Narayana* is not part of the curse according to the source provided (how could that even be considered a curse at all?), so please update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Where did he live before the start of the Satya yuga?